# Font error in pdf report with Gujarati language, Unicode supports the PDF report

Tags: pdf, fonts, report, odoo

[While any words of gujarati language it shows squeres in pdf report like shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G53Hu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install required fonts for gujarati language

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-gujr-extra
```